# can not include std array in dev c++ 5.9

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++

I wanted to include array in DEv C++ 5.9 but it gave an error:

```
32  2   c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\c++0x_warning.h    [Error] #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

Is this because of the version of DEV-C++ that I am using or my computer IOS? I used other versions of DEV C++ but since I have a windows 8 on my computer, they did not work on that and I needed to use this version of DEV C++. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well, as the error states, you have to enable support for C++11 by using the compiler flags. Did you try this already?

Answer (score 7):

The error message tells you exactly how to fix the error.

> #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be
>   enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options

Read your IDE documentation to figure out how to do this or refer to this image.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/devcpp/devcpp2.png

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I just started learning c++ yesterday so anything looks new to me.

Answer (score 1):

In DEV C++ , tools << set the compiler to debug/release << Setting << Code Generation << Language standard(-std) << ISO C++11 or GCC C++11 (whatever you use) << complie your code of std::array using debug/release whatever you used earlier..

Answer (score 0):

> Is this because of the version of DEV-C++ that I am using or my
>   computer IOS?

No, it depends on the C++ compiler version.

As the error says:

> This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
>   standard.